# VBA - ParseJson(http.responsetext) returns “error 13: type mismatch”

Tags: vba

I'm working on a project to get data from an API.
My test kind of work well.

after i got higher than 14, it begins to have the error 13 type mismatch and it stops

Could someone help me understaning why do I have the error

> If json("meta")("total") is "type incompatibility"

I ran my maccro so much times tat for now it runs to i = 103 before I got the error.

I put the code I use below so that you may see some mistakes of improvements and the cause of the error I receive.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Sub Test()
    'create object to receive datas
    Dim http As Object, json As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'process the data
    i = 1
    k = 2
    While i <= 200
        Dim j As String
        j = i
        Dim url As String
        url = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/encyclopedia/vehicles/?application_id=demo&tank_id=" & i
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        http.send
        Set json = ParseJson(http.responsetext)

        If json("meta")("total") <> null Then
            ' Tank id
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 1).Value = json("data")(j)("tank_id")
            ' Tank is premium or Standard
            If json("data")(j)("is_premium") = False Then
                Sheets(2).Cells(k, 2).Value = "Standard"
                Else: Sheets(2).Cells(k, 2).Value = "Premium"
            End If
            ' Tank name
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 3).Value = json("data")(j)("name")
            ' Tank nation
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 4).Value = json("data")(j)("nation")
            ' Tank best Radio
            Dim radios As Integer
            radios = 0
            For Each Item In json("data")(j)("radios")
                If Item > radios Then radios = Item Else radios = radios
            Next Item
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 5).Value = radios
            ' End of Tank Values, next
            i = i + 1
            k = k + 1
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend

    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

[EDIT]
I tried with "on error resume next" formula that way

```
While i <= 100
    j = i
    Dim url As String
    url = myurl & i
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send
    Set response = ParseJson(http.responsetext)

    On Error Resume Next

    If IsNull(response("meta")("total")) Then
    Else:
        ' Tank id
        Sheets(1).Cells(k, 1).Value = response("data")(j)("tank_id")
        ' Tank is premium or Standard
        If response("data")(j)("is_premium") = False Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(k, 2).Value = "Standard"
            Else: Sheets(1).Cells(k, 2).Value = "Premium"
        End If
        ' Tank name
        Sheets(1).Cells(k, 3).Value = response("data")(j)("name")
        ' Tank nation
        Sheets(1).Cells(k, 4).Value = response("data")(j)("nation")
        ' Tank best Radio
        Dim radios As Integer
        radios = 0
        For Each Item In response("data")(j)("radios")
            If Item > radios Then radios = Item Else radios = radios
        Next Item
        Sheets(1).Cells(k, 5).Value = radios
        ' End of Tank Values, next
        k = k + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Now the error does not show, but nothing is writen in the sheet too.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx)

> Expressions that you might expect to evaluate to **True** under some circumstances, such as `If Var = Null` and `If Var <> Null`, are always **False**. This is because any expression containing a **Null** is itself **Null** and, therefore, **False**.

The correct way to test for a non-`Null` is

```
If Not IsNull(json("meta")("total")) Then
```

---

That will only work if `json` returns an actual `Variant/Null` value.

If it just returns a zero-length string, you should probably use:

```
If json("meta")("total") <> vbNullString Then
```

If it returns a `Variant/Empty`, you should use:

```
If Not IsEmpty(json("meta")("total")) Then
```

---

Note:  This doesn't explain why you are getting a "type incompatibility" error, nor why it doesn't crash on the same iteration each time you run the code.  It simply explains why nothing within your `If` statement is being processed.